# duplicate database in civiCRM

Tags: database

Is it possible to duplicate the data base on Civi ? (contacts) Because i need to do it for my traineeship.I don't even know if it's possible but maybe does an alternativ way to do it. thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Do you need it just be a stand-alone copy that people can play with and that can be refreshed once in awhile, or does it need to be synced in real time? It is possible but you will want to set up a separate installation of your website and civicrm. I have a test site/playground set up like that. Let me know. Also, are you a developer or are you training to use the CRM?

Comment: Thx for the answer. It needs to be a simple copy that can be refreshed. And i'm training CRM ( 1st year in an informatic school ).

Comment: Well, just set up a local copy of your website and the CiviCRM by following the instructions. Then import a copy of your CiviCRM database. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/installation-and-basic-set-up/

Comment: There is no feature through the UI that lets you duplicate your whole set up since this also involves the CMS etc. Hence suggest you do what Christia says - and CHristia might want to repaste that as an answer

Comment: I want to suggest retitling this to 'Is there a method via the UI to duplicate database in civiCRM" as i think that may be what is intended

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature through the UI that lets you duplicate your whole set up since this also involves the CMS etc. Hence suggest you do what Christia suggested in the comments, namely

> set up a local copy of your website and the CiviCRM by following the [instructions](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/installation-and-basic-set-up/). Then import a copy of your CiviCRM database.